# Linux equivalents of Windows / DOS terms

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, conversion, ms-dos

I am trying to adjust to Linux terms after many years of DOS and Windows. I have been wanting to switch from Windows to Linux for years now, but couldn't decide on a flavor. Today I got fed up with Windows 7 and just picked one--Ubuntu.

I know Linux has different terms and the file system is a little different. Right now I am trying to find the Linux equivalent of the root directory. My external drives all have their proper names, but the C: drive's name apparently was changed. I would like to change it back, if possible.

Is there a glossary or something that can be used?

Comment: Before other answers will swarm in, YOUR files are in your HOME folder. /home/username. THAT'S WHERE YOU PUT EVERYTHING. The others are non important for now.

Answer (score 2):

Windows and Linux have very different partition naming conventions.

**First** C: Drive is not a whole disk drive but just one partition. In Linux, drives are often referred to as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` etc. The partitions inside the drives are indicated by the numbered suffix, such as `/dev/sda1`. `/dev/sda2` etc.

**Second,** the partitioned need to be mounted before they can be used in Linux. The place where they are mounted are called mount points. A special mount point is `/`, or the root of the file system. This mount point is reserved for Ubuntu system partition, the rough equivalent of Windows `C:\`

**Third,** other non-system partitions can be mounted anywhere as in a folder or sub-folder. For example, if you have a partition for music files, you could mount it in your home folder like `/home/[userID]/Music`.

**Fourth,** if your `C:\` partition has a name, Ubuntu will try to use that name to mount that partition. If not, you can make Ubuntu mount it folder that you name. For example, you can create a folder `/media/OldStinkyC_Drive` and mount your C:\ partition there! Note, unlike Windows everything in Ubuntu is case sensitive.

Here is a reference of DOS to Linux commands:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/unix_for_dos_users.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I've found these DOS-to-Linux Terminal cheat sheets, hope they help!:

- http://www.junauza.com/2009/11/dos-to-unixlinux-translation-dos-to.html
- http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat6.2/gsg-62/ch-doslinux.html

In order to better understand how the Terminal syntax works, I recommend this page:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Just a curiosity: if you eventually get used to the Linux commands and see yourself in a situation where you're using both DOS and Linux, you might want to find out how to run the Linux terminal on Windows before you start smashing keyboards. Take a look at this Q&A:

- https://superuser.com/questions/257140/run-linux-terminal-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's root directory is FileSystem marked (`/`) you can see it and access your file system when you click on your Home Folder in building list tree you can see FileSystem it will be your ex `C:` that you used to have in your Windows, when you click the properties you'll see that it equals to your ex `C:` hdd size that you used to have. For renaming/changing partitions use GParted you can download it at Ubuntu Software Center or using Synaptic Manager. More details about Ubuntu's partitions you can find over [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Comment: How do you uninstall a program and install a program from a unix archive?

Comment: Oh no. Ubuntu has the administrator/owner nonsense too. Nuts. This is one of the things I hated about Windows 7.

Comment: read this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) also you can install it with Ubuntu Software Center right click on a file and choose. To uninstall you can use Synaptic Manager again or commands in Terminal (Ctrl Alt T) `sudo apt-get remove NAME` or/and `sudo apt-get purge NAME` to remove including config files

Comment: The programs I want to install are not listed in the USC. It is on one of my external drives in a folder containing Linux versions of my more useful Windows programs.

Comment: @Rod this is not a forum, not meant for discussions. If you have new facts add them to your question, if you have additional questions ask them in a separate post.